# What should I change in Qt creator to compile using MinGW rather than microsoft compiler

Tags: c++, windows, qt, mingw, qt-creator

Currently my qmake command in QtCreator looks like this:

```
qmake.exe D:\programing\myproject\myproject.pro -r -spec win32-msvc2010 "CONFIG+=debug"
```

Now I do not like the `win32-msvc2010` because Microsoft compiler <del>sucks horribly</del> doesn't support C++0x.

So what configuration do I change to **use MinGW instead of Microsoft compiler when compiling desktop Windows application**?

I walked through the settings and googled but no hints...

Comment: You should either download Qt library, compiled for MingW or compile it yourself. AFAIK there can not be a simple switch,

Comment: Ok, I found the [download link](http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-5) now. Still, once I have it, I need to tell QtCreator to use it. How do I do that?

Comment: does this answer your question? "Select Tools > Options > Build & Run > Kits > Add." - http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-targets.html

Comment: Use Qt Maintenance Tool to add a MinGW kit and it should be automatic. Also see https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-targets.html

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing to do would be to go here:

[Link to Qt downloads page](http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2)

Scroll down and select `Qt 5.6.0 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.9.2, 1.0 GB)` this will download the installer (its about 1 GB). Run it and choose all the default options. Then you will have Qt 5.6 with mingw and Qt Creator all setup ready to go.
Note: Before you start that its probably best to delete your current version - if you are not attached to it in any way :)

If you want to change your current setup, then it might be longer-winded to find out what you are missing for mingw. For example you need the mingw qmake (and all the other stuff under the mingw_32 folder) file that would be located here (using default install options):

- `C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\mingw492_32\bin\qmake.exe`

to create your "Qt Version" part of the kit. And the actual mingw compiler, which is located here (using default install options):

- `C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\Tools\mingw492_32\bin\g++.exe`

to create your compiler. Once you have both of these then you can put them together to create your new kit.

But to just add a compiler all you need to do is:

- Click compilers tab
- Click add and select mingw
- A new compiler is added, click it
- You will see some options below, add your compiler executable path in (like the one above for example).
- And you are done - there are some other options, but you probably don't need to use them.

**note** my paths are for qt 5.5.1 (obviously) so slightly different to 5.6 :)